# Generate mousemove event with dispatchevent?

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, dispatchevent

Is there anyway to do a mousemove event with java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)?

```
.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(client.a
                           .getComponentAt(1, 1),
                               MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED,
                               System.currentTimeMillis(),
                               MouseEvent.NOBUTTON,
                               x,y,
                               1,
                               false));
```

I got this now but it doesnt perform a mouse move.
How can i do it?

Edit:
I tried it like this but its not working:

```
.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(client.a
                           .getComponentAt(1, 1),
                               MouseEvent.MOUSE_MOVED,
                               System.currentTimeMillis(),
                               MouseEvent.NOBUTTON,
                               x,y,
                               0,
                               false));
```

Thanks,
Jeffrey

Comment: I know of no way to do this the way you're trying as the MouseEvent (as far as I understand it) is for sending mouse messages to components not the operating system. Usually I've used the Robot class or [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) to actually move the mouse cursor on the screen.

Comment: Do you want your component to react on a MouseEvent which did not actually happened (faking mouse events), or do you want to move the cursor on the screen ?

Comment: Like a virtual mouse. On a applet.

Comment: @JeffreyGearsoffun: answer given in comment. If you want it official, I'll make it an "answer".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know of no way to do this the way you're trying as the MouseEvent (as far as I understand it) is for sending mouse messages to components not the operating system. Usually I've used the Robot class or [JNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Access) to actually move the mouse cursor on the screen.

Comment: Can you give me a explaination or a link how to do it with JNA?

Comment: @JeffreyGearsoffun: why not make it a **lot** easier on yourself and try using the [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class first.

Comment: I want a virtual mouse btw. not that the main cursor moves
It needs to be used only by the applet

Comment: @JeffreyGearsoffun: OK, now I'm confused. Please let me know what you mean by "virtual mouse"?

Comment: A mouse that can only used in the applet like what you see on bots.

Comment: I think i've got it btw lemme test

Answer (score 4):

I use [Abbot](http://abbot.sourceforge.net/doc/overview.shtml) to emulate MouseEvent in my application. It was recently updated by an Oracle employee for Java 6, JUnit 4, etc.